# Can't call a function from a function Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I come from a Java and C# background and learning python. I am wondering why this piece of code gives me an error in pycharm that says

```
    Unresolved Reference 'methodA'
```

with this code

```
    def a():
        print("hi")

    def b():
        a()
```

Comment: you're calling methodA  and the method is called a ?

Comment: Is it in a class? Try `def b(self): self.a()`

Comment: It works totally fine for me, and IIRC,  there isn't any `Unresolved Reference` error in python?

Comment: http://ideone.com/Ret6HD your example works

Comment: @ShamilKMuhammed Not a Python error but a complaint tooltip from his IDE (PyCharm).

Comment: In future, please provide a **complete** sample program that **actually demonstrates** the error. Do not abbreviate or summarize your sample program. If the sample is short enough, it doesn't require abbreviation. Please copy-paste the shortest complete program that demonstrates your question, and please copy-paste the entire error message.  See [mcve] and [ask] for more info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code (the entire code you posted) should work perfectly, because the name `a` has been introduced into the global scope:

```
def a():
    print("hi")

def b():
    a()

b()  # call b, which in turn calls a
```

But this code (what you are probably quoting from) should fail, because the name `a` is a member of `C`. Member names are not in scope inside other member functions:

```
class C:
    def a():
        print("hi")

    def b():
        a()
o = C()
o.b()  # should fail for several reasons.
```

Also note that, unlike C++ or Java's implicit `this` pointer, the `self` reference must always be explicitly used. Try this instead:

```
class C:
    def a(self):
        print("hi")

    def b(self):
        self.a()

o = C()
o.b()  # calls C.b(o), which in turn calls C.a(o)
```

Comment: what do you mean my member name ?